# Search filter in cakephp with dynamic options

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, filter

I want to apply search filters in my project. I have options tables where options are being saved with the option values with parent id of option id. For example brand is saving as option with parent id set to 0 and all brands have brand id as their parent id set and while saving product I am saving product options in product_options table. Now i want to apply filters in product listing page. I am using following code for filtration:

```
$conditions = array();
$product_options = $this->ProductOption->find('list',array('fields'=>array('product_id'),'conditions'=>array('ProductOption.option_value_id'=>$data['data']['options'])));

$conditions = array_merge($conditions,array('Product.id'=>array_unique($product_options)));
$prod_info = $this->paginate('Product',$conditions);
$this->set(compact('prod_info'));
```

When I search any product with their brand name it works fine but if I try to search with the price (also an option) then it gives other brand products also which have price equal to filter price option. Please check following link to understand problem correctly.

http://primemart.in/Food-Processors-Ii4zRGAKYAo=

Please anyone help me to come out my problem.
Thanks.

Please have a look on my code which I used to pass conditions in and to get results

```php
$product_options = $this->ProductOption->find('list',array(
    'fields'=>array('product_id'),
    'conditions'=>array('ProductOption.option_value_id'=>$data['data']['options'])
));
//$this->Option->unBindModel(array('belongsTo'=>'Product'));
$product_options = $this->Option->find('all', array(
    'conditions'=>array('Option.id'=>$data['data']['options'])
));
//pr($product_options);
$opt_arr = array();

foreach ($product_options as $op) {
    $opt_arr[$op['Option']['parent_id']][] = $op['Option']['id'];
}
$conditions_arr = array();  

foreach($opt_arr as $opt) {
    $key_arr = array();
    foreach($opt as $op) {
        $key_arr['OR']['ProductOption.option_value_id'][] = $op;                        
    }
    $conditions_arr['AND'][] = $key_arr;
}                   
$pr_options = $this->ProductOption->find('list', array(
    'conditions'=>$conditions_arr,
    'fields'=>array('product_id')
));                 
$conditions = array_merge($conditions, array('Product.id'=>array_unique($pr_options)));
```

Comment: I guess query formed has OR condition in it whereas you need AND in your query. You can combine the conditions with AND to get desired result.

Comment: @cartina i have also tried using AND condition. But still this is not working.

Comment: show us how have you tried using AND

Comment: Pls paste your query here.

Comment: why are you assigning 2 times to $product_options variable?

Comment: @scx I have commented the first line of $product_options code which was working before. Now only second line of $product_options is working. But I am still not getting desired results from the code. Please suggest me where I am wrong. 
Thanks.

Comment: Check SQL that your query generates and try switching AND with OR there, I am not also sure what is in the $conditions variable? On the other hand you should not to that like this.. you should check how your model are assosiated and retrive that in one find

Answer (score 1):

I would try code bellow. I assume that $conditions constist of the other conditions you mention in your question.

```
$conditions = ... // other conditions you mentioned 

$conditions = array('AND'=>array($conditions, array('Product.id'=>array_unique($product_options))));
$prod_info = $this->paginate('Product',$conditions);
```